# SQL Server Configuration

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to copy an existing instance of SQL Server 2008 R2. I have a databse that is set up with the security etc already sorted. I want to deploy an installation of SQL Server 2008 R2 with the application I have developed but the user should have no interaction at all.

Comment: Do you mean the user doesn't even have SQL Server installed before your application is installed, or do they have it installed, and you're just deploying a database and users to it?

Comment: The user wont have SQL Server installed at all. Its being designed as a single package application

Comment: It is possible to copy an existing instance of SQL Server by dump and restore.  However the licensing of SQL Server 2008 would have to be sorted out for your user's installation, and it's unclear how much work you are willing to do for said user to install SQL Server for them.  But then you say the user won't have SQL Server installed at all, "Its being designed as a single package application."  You'll need to use a different database manager or host the database server yourself if that's the case, in which case you might as well host the entire application, which I suspect isn't your intent.

Comment: Ok if thats the case is there a way to setup SQL Server 2008, Then set up the user logins (maybe command line??), and then restore or even attach the database (again maybe from command line??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an embedded version of sql server 2008 that is free to distribute:
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx

However, it doesn't support all the nice goodness that 2008 does so it depends on how complex your sql code is.....

Comment: I can't see if this allows the use of Full Text searching so I dont think it will be suitable, The only option i've found is to install SQL Server 2008 from command line, then use SQLCMD to create the tables and logins etc so this may be the only way.